# Regex not selecting first occurrence of text

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex which filters a text for all of its IP addresses. However, there is a problem! It gets ALL of the unrelated text EXCEPT for the text preceding. For example, first, use this website:

http://myregexp.com/signedJar.html

Make the regex:

```
(?<=[0-9]{1,4}+\.[0-9]{1,4}+\.[0-9]{1,4}+\.[0-9]{1,4}+)([[^\n][\n]](?![0-9]{1,3}+\.[0-9]{1,3}+\.[0-9]{1,3}+\.[0-9]{1,3}+))*[[^\n]\n]
```

And make the input:

This text will not be selected 1.1.1.1 however, the rest 2.2.22.345 of this t 4.55.62.1 ext will be selected 32.4.3.1 just fine

You should see something like this:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/LzZWl.png]

So my question is, what is the best way to make the "This text will not be selected " become selected? (or any text preceding the first IP)

Comment: I would reduce your IP pattern such as: \b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d?\d)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d?\d)\b

Comment: @godspeedlee, that captures all of the IPs, not the text surrounding the IPs :(

Comment: maybe you can try split string with IP?

Comment: @godspeedlee a good idea! But i was hoping to get rid of the excess via regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're making this job a lot harder than it needs to be.  If you just want to grab all the IP addresses, why not match them directly?  For example:

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    matchList.add(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had an idea! A very simple solution is to append 1.1.1.1 to the beginning of the string and then ignore first IP returned by my regex split (split suggested by godspeedlee -- if you want to add an answer and claim the votes for this, I will accept)

Answer (score -1):

this: 
    ?<=

means non-capturing group, try to remove this and see what is selected.

Comment: `(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind.